# Rpsec check existence and value of a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to test a existence of a User model attribute.
So I write like this.

```
describe "Authentications" do
  it "sign up with twitter" do
    visit new_user_session_path
    expect { click_link "Sign up with Twitter"}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end
  describe "new user" do
    let(:new_user) { User.last }
    it "should have slug" do
      #new_user its(:slug) { should eq("foo") }
      new_user.slug should exist
    end
  end
end
```

First test passes, but second test fails with error like this.

```
  1) Authentications new user should have slug
     Failure/Error: new_user.slug should exist
     NoMethodError:
       "new user" does not respond to either #exist? or #exists?
     # ./spec/features/autentication_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I think I'm calling method wrong way. How should I use it?

After all I want to check not only existence of it but also the value of it. But it fails also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to validate presence of a value you should use the method `present?` that Rails provides.

`expect(new_user.slug).to be_present` should work for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the failing expectation you have is equivalent to:

```
new_user.slug(subject.should(exist))
```

This is why your failure message refers to "new user", which is the description of our example and thus the implicit value of `subject`.

Presumably, you intended the `should` to have been applied to `new_user.slug`, in which case, you should have written:

```
new_user.slug.should exist
```

However, that will only exist if the value of `new_user.slug` has an `exist?` method defined on it (per https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-99/docs/built-in-matchers/exist-matcher), which strings do not.

If you want to test whether something is simply `truthy`, then you can use:

```
new_user.slug.should be
```

If you want to exclude `false` as a value, then you can use:

```
new_user.slug.should_not be_nil
```

The rest of this answer deals with a separate matter, which may or may not impact your test depending on whether or not you have a `User` in your database prior to the overall `describe` block being invoked.

Assuming you're operating with transactions *on*, the user created in your initial `it` block does not exist in the body of your subsequent `describe`, so `User.first` is going to return `nil`, which explains your errors.

If you want to check that your sign in changes the user count by one *and* use that sign in with a separate test, you can use a `let` expression as in the following:

```
describe "Authentications" do
  let(:sign_in) do
    visit new_user_session_path
    click_link "Sign up with Twitter"
  end
  it "sign up with twitter" do
    expect { sign_in }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end
  describe "new user" do
    let(:new_user) { User.last }
    before { sign_in }
    it "should have slug" do
      #new_user its(:slug) { should eq("foo") }
      new_user.slug should exist
    end
  end
end
```

If you want to combine these tests for purposes of understanding the slug failure, you can do so as follows:

```
describe "Authentications" do
  it "sign up with twitter" do
    visit new_user_session_path
    expect { click_link "Sign up with Twitter" }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    User.last.slug should exist
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, so that was scope problem. But after changing the spec as you write, test fails still with same error. I assured that ` config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` in spec helper. What should I check next?

Comment: I thought maybe I'm editing completely wrong file, so I changed first test to `change(User, :count).by(2)`. And I affirmed the first test also fails.

Comment: My answer explained why the user created by your original "click link" is not available to the subsequent test. If you can't do multiple Twitter sign-ups or if the slug of the created user doesn't exist, those are separate issues. While you probably want to keep these tests separate in the long run and perhaps transition to a different way for creating users for test purposes, as things stand now I could combine the two examples into one and make sure that works.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but I couldn't combine two test into one, because I don't figure out how to `expect` and `before`. I'll read a book through again and try it later.

Comment: See updated answer with the tests combined, which should allow you to confirm the `.slug` behavior. As an aside, I noticed that you've asked 97 questions and only upvoted 18 answers across the whole site. And on this question alone, I've addressed three separate issues. You might want to take a look at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and the last paragraph in particular.

Comment: I see. the test you showed me fails and `User.last.slug should_not exist` and `User.last should exist` also fails.